# Subscript Access to Individual Struct Fields

Tags: c++, pointers

I've come across the following code in 'Foundations of Game Engine Development - 01 Mathematics'. The complete code listing can be accessed [here](http://foundationsofgameenginedev.com/FGED1-code.cpp)

```
struct Vector3D
{
    float x, y, z;

    float& operator[](int i)
    {
        return ((&x)[i]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how the [] operator gives access to the fields y and z?

The way I think this works is by first get the address to x, then doing pointer arithmetic to get each individual field. That being the case, how do you guarantee that x,y,z are contiguous in memory?

Comment: It provides access via undefined behavior.

Comment: The author of that book should feel bad. And you should get a better book to make better use of your time.

Comment: "how do you guarantee that x,y,z are contiguous in memory" – you don't; you keep your fingers crossed. (At a glance, there seems to be more undefined behaviour in that code. Remember to cross your fingers.)

Comment: @molbdnilo you can declare the struct with packed 1-byte alignment to remove any padding between fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain how the `[] operator` gives access to the fields `y` and `z`?

It does not. Even though the code appears working, the behavior is undefined.

> How do you guarantee that `x`, `y`, `z` are contiguous in memory?

There is no such guarantee:

> Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other

A better approach to implementing this class would be to use an array of three elements, and then to add member functions returning references to `x`, `y`, and `z`:

```
struct Vector3D {
    std::array<float,3> v;
    float& operator[](int i) {
        return v[i];
    }
    float& x() {
        return v[0];
    }
    float& y() {
        return v[1];
    }
    float& z() {
        return v[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad my eyebrow-raising was justified when reading the code.

Comment: @Compton A really bad thing about UB is that the code with it "just works" more often than it should. In fact, I don't think there is a compiler that would generate a binary that breaks the code from the book. Still, even a theoretical possibility of undefined behavior is, well, undefined behavior, so it should be avoided.